# Postgres VARCHAR not displaying in html table

Tags: node.js, postgresql, rest, express, ejs

I am currently moving a node/express application from a mongodb setup to a postgres setup. I have a page (report.ejs) which displays a table of items and whether they are "True" or "False". However, it appears that the report is not displaying the these "true" or "false" values, despite them being saved successfully in the database when I access the table in the SQL Shell.

Here is an example of the div structure. `pipeline.url` and `pipeline.score` are succesfully displaying on the webpage, however `pipeline.firstItem`, `pipeline.secondItem` and all the other items are not displaying in the table.

report.ejs sample code:

```
<div id="main_content_wrap" class="outer">
    <section id="main_content" class="inner"> 
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="mb-1" id="reportURL"><%= pipeline.url %></h1>
        <div class="text-muted mb-2" id="reportDate">
          <%= pipeline.createdAt %>
        </div>
        <div class="text-muted mb-2">
          Score Succesfully Saved
        </div>
        <div class="text-muted mb-2">
          <%= pipeline.score %>
        </div>

        <table id="upcReport">
            <tr>
                <th>Items</th>
                <th>Implemented</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Header 1</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>This is the first item</td>
                <td><%= pipeline.firstItem %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>This is the second item</td>
                <td><%= pipeline.secondItem %></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <button onclick="exportData()">Download Report</button><br>

        <a href="/" class="btn btn-secondary">Home</a>
        <a href="/pipelines/edit/<%= pipeline.id %>" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

This is despite the fact that each item in the table has been set-up with a `VARCHAR(100)` datatype.  I have attempted using `BOOLEAN` and `TEXT` datatypes but the issue persists.

Table creation smaple from server.js

```
  const sql_create_pipeline = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Pipelines (
  pipeline_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  slug VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  gear VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  app VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  url VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  score VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  createdAt VARCHAR(100),
  firstItem VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  secondItem VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  );`;
```

Comment: I don't know anything about pipeline, but looking at the columns that do work vs. those that don't, I'm going to guess that it's related to the capitalization.  Your create table statement would create columns with all lower case names - they have to be double quoted to create upper case names.  Stick with the lower case names as they are much easier to deal with, but you may have to change your references to them in your code.

Comment: I see a pattern all lower case items are displayed, mixed case are not. Check what the actual column names are in the table in the database and add the information tou your query.

Comment: @Jeremy @Adrian Klaver you were correct. I changed `pipeline.firstItem` to `pipeline.firstitem` and it is now displaying correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, the issue was simply that I had uppercase characters in `pipeline.firstItem` and `pipeline.secondItem`. Changing them to `pipeline.firstitem` and `pipeline.seconditem` fixed the issue.